# How to get notified if we move to next page in CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I would like to get notified if I move to the next page in CarouselView in Xamarin.Forms.

Is it possible?
Any event or property or method available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`CarouselView` has an `ItemSelected` event that can be subscribe to:

```
PizzDeals.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.SelectedItem);
    var pizza = e.SelectedItem as SpecialtyPizzaDeals;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pizza.name);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sushi. Is there any way to change any property of the view loaded inside a carousel view(for example, Label) in the next page of the carousel view?

Comment: @Divakar Normally you would do that by data binding within your MVVM, take a look at the https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/ /  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys